# Encog - Error saving network weights, Not a valid EG file

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, encog

I've got a network trained and I want to save it and be able to load it later so I don't have to re-train it... duh.

End of training code:

```
 //Save network
 SerializeObject.save(new File("encognet"),network);
 Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
```

Loading File

```
BasicNetwork network = (BasicNetwork) EncogDirectoryPersistence.loadObject(new File("encognet"));
```

I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" org.encog.persist.PersistError: Not a valid
>   EG file.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not saving the file as an `.eg` extension. If this is not the problem, I'm not sure about `SerializeObject.save`, but I know that `EncogDirectoryPersistence` works for me.

So, test out this code for saving

```
    public static final String FILENAME = "test_load_net.eg";
    EncogDirectoryPersistence.saveObject(new File(FILENAME), network);
```

And then load like this

```
    public static final String FILENAME = "test_load_net.eg";

    BasicNetwork network = (BasicNetwork)EncogDirectoryPersistence.loadObject(new File(FILENAME));
```

Comment: @Nate Cook3 - thanks for this! Helped me with the .NET implementation also.